# Maven Jetty Plugin - Disable Http Trace

Tags: jetty, maven-jetty-plugin, end-of-life

I have a maven project with a web.xml and run it using mvn jetty:run
How can I disable the http-tracing?

Edit: I looked [here](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.22.v20170531/reference-section.html#jetty-xml-syntax) but I was unable to identify the relevant tags...

This is the relevant plugin:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version>
    <configuration>
    <jettyXml>src/jetty.xml</jettyXml>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things.

1. [Jetty 9.2 is EOL (End of Life)](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/jetty-announce/msg00116.html) - consider upgrading to something supported and stable (such as the recently released `9.4.14.v20181114`)
2. The `TRACE` method in HTTP is disabled by default ([via the `webdefaults.xml` descriptor](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.14.v20181114/jetty-webapp/src/main/config/etc/webdefault.xml#L505-L522)).

The only way you can use `TRACE` is to *both* intentionally configure your webapp to use a custom default descriptor without this constraint (which your `<configuration>` section doesn't do), *and* have a Servlet that implements [`doTrace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doTrace-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-) or [`service()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#service-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-) methods to support the `TRACE` method.